# Extending RichTextBox combining styles

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, selection, richeditbox

I am using this advRichEdit : http://geekswithblogs.net/pvidler/archive/2003/10/15/188.aspx

and so far it works fine.

What I'm trying to understand is how do I achieve "wavy" + "word" underline styles. As a beginner, I don't understand too much the whole code, so I really don't get where to set that, so that I can use it.

thanks to whoever will help !

Ps : it's *winform* not wpf, nor html.

=== unworking tests ===

```
advRichTextBox1.SelectionUnderlineStyle = AdvRichTextBox.UnderlineStyle.Word && AdvRichTextBox.UnderlineStyle.Wave;
```

-- just to show what I'd like to achieve, (it's not working that way but it's how I would do it)

```
advRichTextBox1.SelectionUnderlineStyle = new Font(advRichTextBox1.SelectionFont, advRichTextBox1.SelectionUnderlineStyle ^ AdvRichTextBox.UnderlineStyle.Wave);
```

Comment: Have you seen (and tested) this comment there? : _Note that some of these styles may not display correctly. This is a common problem with the richedit control, often you will apply some formatting only to find that it will not display at all. The formatting is usually stored though, so cutting and pasting into Word will show the text correctly._

Comment: @TaW Hello, thanks for taking a look at it. Yes, I did see it. My problem in this case is not that it won't display, it's to find out how to do a wavy underline that is word-per-word and so that doesn't underline the spaces between the words.

Comment: Doesn't look as if that is directly possible, read: you will have to select and style all words separately, I'm afraid. BTW: to __combine__ (add) options you must use `|` not `&`let alone `&&`!

Comment: @TaW I guess it's how I'll go. As of now, from what I've tested, the styles are all displayed properly btw. Just in case someone see this and ponder about it.